# Delete item from XML using dropdown list

Tags: jquery, xml, drop-down-menu

I'm using jquery to populate a dropdown box. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Check</title>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "modules.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var select = $('#mySelect');
                $(xml).find('modules').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('MAC').each(function(){
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
                    });
                });
                select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
            }
        });
    });
 </script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <h1>Test</h1>
        <form action="test.asp" onsubmit="" method="post" >
            <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
                <option>loading</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Change">
        </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to give each dropdown item a value corresponding to its position in the xml file, but i have no idea of how to do this. The reason i would like to make this is to be able to delete the item from the xml. Does anyone has any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/each/ can use an index argument in the function:

```
$(xml).find('modules').each(function(module_idx){
  $(this).find('MAC').each(function(mac_idx){
```

With that, you can locate it in the XML file with something like `$(xml).find('modules').eq(module_idx).find('MAC').eq(mac_idx)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It was exactly what i wanted. :D I suppose I didn't look hard enough for it. :s